# Posting multiple values for one argument?

Tags: php, codenameone

I'm trying to post an array to **PHP**, but when I use the code below nothing is transferred and the `$_POST` array comes up as `{}`. How can I post an array to php?

```
MultipartRequest request = new MultipartRequest();
request.setUrl(url);
request.setPost(true);  
String[] value = {"a","b","c"};
request.addArgument(argument, value);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer provided by @tizbn may be valid to some extent but doesn't always work with php, so I used `StringBuilder` like below, but this solution requires you to know the size of your array beforehand:

```
...
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("c");

String[] value = new String[list.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    value[i] = (builder.append("\"").append(list.get(i)).append("\"")).toString();
}
Arrays.toString(value);

ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();
request.setUrl(url);
request.setPost(true);
request.addArgument("arg", value);
...
```

On php side, you read the values as follow:

```
...
$arg = isset($_POST['arg']) ? $_POST['arg'] : '';
$argArray = json_decode($arg);
foreach ($argArray as $value) {
    ...
    // do whatever you want with $value
}
...
```

Comment: FYI this brought my attention to a bug in MultipartRequest where the `addArgument(String[])` method was ignored. This is fixed in the sources.

Comment: @shaiAlmog to make use of the fix, do I need to update something or will it automatically go into effect?

Comment: New server builds should already include it but to get it to work on the simulator you will have to either wait for the next plugin update or use the sources: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html

Answer (score 2):

Use `ConnectionRequest` if you are not attaching files instead of `MultipartRequest`:

```
ConnectionRequest request = new ConnectionRequest();
request.setUrl(url);
request.setPost(true);
```

Use json library to add your array:

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put("hi");
array.put("hello");
String value = array.toString();
```

Then add it as an argument to your request:

```
request.addArgument("argument", value);
```

Comment: Thanks so much and would it not work with a MultipartRequest?

Comment: its for posting large file/s
https://codenameone.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CodenameOne/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html

Comment: I suggest migrating to the new JavaDocs location: https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/MultipartRequest.html comparing the two shows exactly why...